# PHP mysql connect to any remove server the post variables

Tags: php, mysql, remote-server

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $host = $_POST['host'];
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];
    $db = $_POST['db'];
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    $con = @mysqli_connect($host . ":3360", $user, $pass, $db);

    // $con=@mysqli_connect('192.168.100.42','root','vertrigo','skates');
    // Check connection

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    else {
        echo 'connected';
    }

    @mysqli_close($con);
}
```

I'm using this script to access remote db server in local(basically i want to access local db server through live webiste), howewer, I'm getting an error:

> Failed to connect to MySQL: Unknown MySQL server host
>   '192.168.100.42:3360' (11004)

Please help to get out from this.

Comment: For a starter, stop suppressing errors with `@`

Comment: If you are running this script on server then change your ip to localhost because for this script accessing db as localhost

Comment: `192.168.100.42` is a private internal IP address.  Is the web server on the same LAN as the database server?  If not then that address won't work.  The database server would need a publicly resolvable IP address (which likely means opening that port on a router, which *probably* isn't a good idea unless you *really* know what you're doing for securing a database).

Answer (score 1):

192.168.100.42 looks like a local IP. You'd need to try to connect to your static public IP and then forward port 3306 in your router to the 192.168.100.42 machine.

That's not your only problem;

Just because $_POST is not empty, don't assume it has those array keys set and not empty. Syntax like

```
if(isset($_POST['user'] && !empty($_POST['user'])))
```

Is much better.

Also, never use $_POST on any database interaction without sanitisation, and never connect to a database with the root user.

I don't know your exact application, but it's impossibly insecure.